# Java ProcessBuilder calling another java with arguments

Tags: java

I want to use ProgressBuilder to run another jar with arguments inserted.

Example: `es.jar` file with `Main` class, and an arg `sl`.
I know I can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` like this:

```
String arg = "sl";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp \"es.jar " + arg + "\" Main");
```

If I use `ProgressBuilder`, **without the arg `sl`**, it would be like this:

```
processBuilder.command("java","-cp","es.jar", "Main").start();
```

However, arg `sl` is needed, how can I insert it? I have tried the following codes but obviously none of them work:

```
processBuilder.command("java","-cp","es.jar sl", "Main").start(); // failed
processBuilder.command("java","-cp","\"es.jar sl\"", "Main").start(); // failed also
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer It would not work as intended, since it would try to find `sl` class to run main function, which do not exist.

Comment: Have you tried flipping them? `processBuilder.command("java","-cp","es.jar", "Main", arg).start();` - But I'm left thinking, can you send parameters to a class this way...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Flipping them does work! Thanks, that is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java -cp "es.jar sl" Main` makes no sense, and I'm pretty sure it would otherwise fail

`java` states `java [-options] class [args...]`, so the first parameter after the options is the class to be executed, so based on your question, that would mean it needs to be

`java -cp es.jar Main sl`, or in more specifically, in regards to your question, `processBuilder.command("java","-cp","es.jar", "Main", arg).start();`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following command instead:

```
java -cp es.jar Main
```